# Code for ADC input not working

Tags: assembly, arduino, atmega

I am trying to read in a value from a potentiometer using the ADC and then use it to set the length of my delay which will in turn light different lights for a certain interval (dependant on the input from the ADC). I might be making a simple error. Here is the code so far:`

`    initialize:

```
 LDI R16, HIGH(RAMEND)  ;Initializing the r16 register

 OUT SPH, R16
 LDI R16, LOW(RAMEND)
 OUT SPL, R16   

LDI R16, 0xFF   
OUT DDRB, R16   ;Initializes port B as output
LDI R16, 0x00
OUT DDRC, R16   ;Initializes port C as an input

LDI R16, 0b00000000; Initialize ADC port and reference voltage
STS ADMUX, R16 

startADC:
LDI R16, 0b11000111
STS ADCSRA, R16 ;Begins converstion 
KeepPolling:
LDI R16, ADCSRA
SBRS R16, 4     ;Checks if bit is set
RJMP KeepPolling    ;If bit is not set, conversion continues
LDS R18, ADCL       ;Loads ADCL value onto R16  
LDS R16, ADCH       ;Readvalue so resistor doesnt lock down
RCALL   Green


Green:

MOV R16, R18            ;Load value of ADC to R24
SBI PORTB, 0b00000001       ;Output High to portb
RCALL loop
CBI PORTB, 0b00000001
RCALL Yellow        ;Go to yellow if R24 is 0



Yellow: 

MOV R16, R18            ;Load value of ADC to R24
LSR R16             ;Divide R24 by 2
SBI PORTB, 0b00000010       ;Output high to port B 
CALL loop
CBI PORTB, 0b00000010
RCALL Red

Red:

MOV R16, R18
SBI PORTB, 0b00000011
RCALL loop
CBI PORTB, 0b00000011
RCALL startADC


loop: 

MOV R20, R16 

outer_loop: 

LDI R24, 0

Add_Dec:    

ADIW R24, 1
BRNE Add_Dec
DEC R20
BRNE outer_loop 
RET
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the KeepPolling loop does **not** read the ADC status register:

```
LDI R16, ADCSRA
```

Maybe you want a LDS instruction there.  Depending on the AVR, you might be able to use the SBI instruction.

Also, `startADC()` calls `Green()` which calls `Yellow()` which calls `Red()` which calls `startADC()`. I think you'll run out of stack space pretty fast.

Also, once you break that infinite loop, `Yellow()` calls `Red()`, and then continues directly into `Red()`. Same with `Green()` falling into `Yellow()`.

Comment: How could I possibly change the code to not run out of stack space? And could you elaborate on the last section of your comment, not too sure I understand the meaning ? Thanks